# Telegram Bot receive video from user

Tags: python, image, video, bots, telegram

i want my bot to receive videos thats been sent by users. Previously, i did this coding to receive images from users but i still cant use my bot to receive videos from them. Can any of you help me solve this problem?
coding:

```
file = update.message.photo[-1].file_id
```

Answer (score 0):

At first place telegram can recieve two types of videos: simple videofile, that was sent by user as attachment and "video_note" - video that was created directly in the telegram.
Recieving both these types are pretty similar:

At first we need to obtain file_id:

```
def GetVideoNoteId(update):
    if update['message'].get('video_note') != None:
        return update['message']['video_note']['file_id']
    else:
        return 'not videonote'
```

second step - getting filepath of that file on telegram servers - from where we should download that file:

```
def GetVideoNoteFileSource(FileId):
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TOKEN + '/' + 'getFile'
    jsn = {'file_id': FileId}
    r = requests.get(url,json=jsn).json()
    fileSource = r['result']['file_path']
    return fileSource
```

And third - finally - getting this file:

```
def GetFile(fileSource):
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' + TOKEN + '/' + fileSource
    r = requests.get(url)
    filename = 'Video.mp4'
    try:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(r.content)
        return 'file dowloaded'
    except:
        return 'there are something wrong'
```

With videofile as attachments similar, but
`return update['message']['video_note']['file_id']` - would be looks different (i do not remmember)